# User friendly WYSIWYG editor for Magento

Tags: magento, wysiwyg

I need to modify the default WYSIWYG editor in Magento it is not user friendly.Is it possible to add a more user friendly WYSIWYG editor to Magento backend?

Help is highly appreciable.

Thanks,
VKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: http://www.mgt-commerce.com/redactor-jquery-wysiwyg-for-magento.html

It's easy, nice and free, having the basic, I think all that somebody actually needs.